# Select following-sibling if child node has attribute

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am creating a scraper for the site:
https://www.oddsportal.com/darts/europe/european-championship/results/

I am using splash plugin to **render javascript**

I want to follow the preceding years to get historical data, the preceding year has the class "inactive". So, I want a Xpath expression that finds the "active" year and get's the **href** for the preceding year.

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<div class="main-menu2 main-menu-gray"><ul class="main-filter"><li><span class="active"><strong><a href="/darts/europe/european-championship/results/">2018</a></strong></span></li><li><span class="inactive"><strong><a href="/darts/europe/european-championship-2017/results/">2017</a></strong></span></li><li><span class="inactive"><strong><a href="/darts/europe/european-championship-2016/results/">2016</a></strong></span>
```

Here is my attempt:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="main-menu2 main-menu-gray"]/ul/following-sibling::li[child::span[@class="active"]]/strong/a/@href').get()
```

I would expect this to return:

```
/darts/europe/european-championship-2017/results/
```

As this is the preceding year for the current url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the options in xpath.

```
(//div[@class="main-menu2 main-menu-gray"]/ul/li[.//span[@class="active"]]/following-sibling::li//a)[1]
```

Simple, but not sure if you have to absolutely relay on the active element.

```
(//div[@class='main-menu2 main-menu-gray']//span[@class='inactive']//a)[1]
```